# modify Gobject load library path for python

Tags: pygobject

In order to troubleshoot my Python Gstreamer app, I cloned and added some debug statements to the [Gstreamer core](https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer).  Now I want Python to load my private build of gstreamer, instead of the standard one in /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/.  For the Gstreamer core, I modified LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but this has no effect.  For the record, I'm running on 3.13.0-91-generic #138-Ubuntu.

I was able to do something similar for Gstreamer plugins using the env var GST_PLUGIN_PATH.  I suspect that Gobject may use it's own environment variable to load libraries, but I haven't found it.

Answer (score 3):

```
gi.require_version('GIRepository', '2.0')
from gi.repository import GIRepository
GIRepository.Repository.prepend_library_path('/my/custom/path')
```

Comment: I think you would want to `.get_default()` on `GIRepository.Repository` before calling the prepend